# How to use General Estimating Equations in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the gee package in the MASS library to look at the association between changes in variable a at 2 time points and changes in variable b between those time points.

```
a.timepoint1 = c(4,8,9,2,4,10)
a.timepoint2 = c(8,12,11,13,9,14)

b.timepoint1 = c(9,7,5,7,10,12)
b.timepoint2 = c(3,1,2,3,9,8)
```

Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

I initially thought that you put delta a (change in a) and delta b into the gee model but I've been told that instead you put the data for both time points in

Comment: Please show your code and expected results

Comment: The way you have formulated the research question, there is no need for GEE at all. You would simply put delta a and delta b in a (univariate) regression model. Also, the question is more suitable for CrossValidated, as it has to do with statistics, not programming.